# What's the relationship between consensus and transaction in computer science?

Tags: transactions, consistency, consensus

One sentence on wiki  confused me, claiming that 2pc is special type of consensus.

[Two-phase_commit_protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)

`In transaction processing, databases, and computer networking, the two-phase commit protocol (2PC) is a type of atomic commitment protocol (ACP). It is a distributed algorithm that coordinates all the processes that participate in a distributed atomic transaction on whether to commit or abort (roll back) the transaction (it is a specialized type of consensus protocol)`

As I know, consensus aims at deciding one single variable's value on difference sides in a system and transaction is likely to ensure multiple variables' value. If I'm right then consensus algorithm shoud be a subset of transaction. Why the opposite??

Comment: "consensus aims at deciding one single variable's value" - which, from your above quote, appears to be a single decision on whether to *commit* or *abort*. The article is talking about 2PC, which is a mechanism used as *part* of transactional processing. It's not trying to say that transactions *as a whole* are a consensus system.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yeah, I misunderstood it. I thought the value  to be determined defined in consensus should be certain concrete variable stored in the databases, never expecting it being an abstraction of status for the result of a set of operations,   the operations in a single atomic transaction.